Convolution with Kronecker delta
I know that convolution with delta shifts a signal. As for example, $x \!\left[ n \right] * \delta \!\left[ n - 2 \right] = x \!\left[ n - 2 \right]$. How to do convolution with $x \!\left[ -n \right]$?
Is $x \!\left[ -n \right] * \delta \!\left[ n - 2 \right] = x \!\left[ -n + 2 \right]$ or $x \!\left[ -n - 2 \right]$?
I think $\delta \!\left[ n - 2 \right] = \delta \!\left[ 2 - n \right]$, then $x \!\left[ -n \right] * \delta \!\left[ 2 - n \right] = x \!\left[ 2 - n \right]$. Is this approach correct?

Anywhere you have an $n$, you want to replace it with a $-n$.

Why don't you write down the convolution sum, so you can be sure what's going on?

expanding on Matt’s reply: $$\delta[n] * x[-n] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \delta[k] x[(-n)-k]$$ - which values of k aren’t 0 in the sum?

it might be better to define $g[n] = x[-n]$. now we know $$x[-n] * \delta[n] = (g*\delta)[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} g[k] \delta [n-k] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x[-k] \delta [n-k]$$ - now think about which value of k isn’t zeroed out by the delta.


Is $x \!\left[ -n \right] * \delta \!\left[ n - 2 \right] = x \!\left[ -n + 2 \right]$ or $x \!\left[ -n - 2 \right]$?

This thing with time reversal is best understood by making use of another symbol.  So define:
$$ \tilde{x}[n] \triangleq x[-n] $$
So then,
$$ x[-n] * h[n] = \tilde{x}[n] * h[n] $$
So we know, for some delay amount $m$, that
$$ \tilde{x}[n] * \delta[n-m] = \tilde{x}[n-m] $$
Now what is $\tilde{x}[n-m]$?  It is $x[-(n-m)] = x[m-n]$.


The operation of $n \to -n$ is basically reflecting the signal.
The convolution with shifted Kronecker Delta is the shifting operator.

So basically the composition of those operations is a shifted reflected signal.
